# python3 terminal code runs fine, but the script does not

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, netcat

When using the Python3 CLI in the Linux terminal by simply calling 'python3' I am able to run and execute the socket code shown below to send a command to a netcat server running on a sensor on my network and I receive the expected return value:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.50.30', 7501))
s.setblocking(True)
snd = s.send(b'\x00\x0dget_sensor_info')
rec = s.recv(1024, 0x40)
print(rec)
```

when I run this same exact code in a script like so: 'python3 test_sensor.py'. this returns the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ouster_uptimme.py", line 9,
> in 
> rec = s.recv(1024, 0x40) BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

I am honestly very confused about what is going on here. this is not my first foray into sockets but I'm thinking there might be something going on from either timing or access level issue.

Open to ideas at this point I have spent a few hours trying to solve this problem and am open to outside input.

Comment: May your socket be hanging? Is there are reason you don't close your socket?

Comment: The flag 0x40 (MSG_DONTWAIT) for `recv` means that the function will return immediately with the error  you see unless there are data already available in the socket buffer. So you are actually calling for trouble by using this flag. Please explain what your intention was here, so that we can suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am expecting a very defined return value from the TCP API of the sensor. This shouldn't hang. It will receive it's reply immediately. And on top of this the Python documents state that the buffer doesn't need to be full for it to send. When I execute this in the Python terminal I get the defined response that I'm looking for. In a script however I am not. Without this recv hangs indefinitely without receiving its reply. So I added this year so that I can just fail quickly rather than wait forever. So set blocking equals true and 0x40 is really just creating an explicit event

Comment: @srn can you explain a little more what you mean by closing the socket?  All of the walkthroughs that show me how to do this suggest to that I don't need to do anything in between sending and receiving. The code is hanging at the receiving side. Do I need to do something that I haven't seen yet and any documents I've read?

Comment: @castaway2000 I was pondering whether you tested this once in the interactive shell, didn't close the socket and left the server hanging, but Steffen Ullrich is right.

Comment: @srn in the interactive shell this 0x40 don't wait command does not return this error. it receives the message as expected from the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Like @SteffenUllrich said in the comments, the issue here is using the `0x40 (MSG_DONTWAIT)` flag.

You can actually replicate the error in your interactive python shell by defining the relevant part as a function:

```
>>> def foo():
    snd = s.send(b'\x00\x0dget_sensor_info')
    rec = s.recv(1024, 0x40)
    print(rec)
...
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The reason you don't see it when pasting line by line is that this *immediately* is not actually *immediately*. **The time passing** between copy, paste and enter is apparently enough for the packet to arrive. Otherwise you'd get the same error. You can see the same behavior, if you time.sleep() a bit before recv and it would work in your script (just to see that this is the issue, it's at least unreliable for actual code).

**Some context:**

You're getting `socket.errno.EAGAIN` / `socket.errno.EWOULDBLOCK` (errno 11) and per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html)
those are mapped to the `exception BlockingIOError`.

This is happening due to using the 0x40 flag, which is hex for MSG_DONTWAIT. This sets the call to non-blocking. While you've set your open file descriptor to blocking, you do the inverse for the recv call.  If `s.recv` does not find any data already present in the buffer, it will raise the aforementioned exception.

> An operation that would block was attempted on an object that has non-blocking mode selected. Trying the same operation again will block until some external condition makes it possible to read, write, or connect (whatever the operation).

Comment: This is not the problem sadly. the message is recv'd in the interactive shell even with 0x40 present. if i remove this i still get the data from the interactive shell. when its in a script the program hangs indefinitely. 

the sensor returns a very defined message immediately after and would not wait for minutes to receive the message. 

so that if its not there within the immediate timeframe it ends. even if i added a time.sleep(1) i should have something in buffer nearly immediately.(< 30ms)

Comment: this is good data for others though. i appreciate the help. i might have to find another way to get the same info.

Comment: @castaway2000 just to make sure I understand correctly: you have removed the 0x40 flag from the script and then the problem changed from BlockingIOError to indefinitely hanging? That'd be a good thing. Having the server close() the client connection or shutdown() and close() client-side or setting another timeout (not 0.0, not indefinitely) could just work.